# Can't connect VS2022 .Net Maui Project with Mac

Tags: c#, xcode, macos, xamarin.forms, maui

I have a Xamarin.Forms and a .NET MAUI project. In Xamarin.Forms, I can connect to my MAC (MacBook Pro 2020 M1) without any issues, but I cannot do the same with my .NET MAUI project.

I'm getting the following output:

Checking host configuration for connection to "MacBookPro-DEV"...
Checking SSH configuration...
Initializing environment...
Checking available disk space...
Checking for Rosetta installation...
Verifying Mono installation...
Checking host configuration for connection to "MacBookPro-DEV"...
Disconnecting from "MacBookPro-DEV"...
Disconnecting from "MacBookPro-DEV"...
Connection to "MacBookPro-DEV" has been terminated.
The object reference has not been set to an instance of an object.

I am developing on a Windows 10 machine with a Windows 10 VM running on it. The Mac and the PC are on the same network and connected via a LAN cable.

Environment:

.NET 6.0
Visual Studio 2022 v17.6.2 and v17.7.3
Visual Studio for Mac v17.6.3
Windows 10
macOS Ventura 13.5.1
Xcode 14.3.1
I have already checked the following:

SSH connection -> Works manually via the command line.
Cleared Xamarin cache on both MAC and Windows.
MAC settings (Remote login, firewall, authorized users, correct IP address).
Visual Studio 2022 settings (tested with v17.6.2 and v17.7.3).
Updated Visual Studio for Mac to 17.6.3.
Cleared Xcode cache.
Mono version 6.12.0.188 -> Installed and included in environment variables.

Connect my VIsual Studio 2022 .Net Maui Project with my MAC and I get an error

Comment: Some of the recent visual studio versions could not connect to mac. One day you could connect, the next day you could not. Search around, there were questions asked.

Comment: Did you solve your issue. I have exactly the same issue, very similar environment (Windows 10 trying to connect to mac OS with .NET 8.0.100. Xamarin.Forms project connects OK but MAUI project returns the same output as you.

Answer (score 1):

> If your log files show a problem during the "Installing", "Uploading", or "Starting" steps for any of Mac agents, you can try deleting the XMA cache folder to force Visual Studio to re-upload them.

As the doc says, you may try deleting the **XMA** folder for both Mac and Windows.

For how to find the path and delete XMA on both OS, you may refer to  [*Clearing the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac) (This doc is about Xamarin and it applies to MAUI). When starting next time, Visual Studio will detect and re-upload them.

After deleting the folder, remember to restart visual studio and visual studio for mac. If you still have any questions, feel free to ask.

Hope it works.

Comment: I already tryed this : "Cleared Xamarin cache on both MAC and Windows. "
But it didn't work after i deleted the files

Comment: You could try reinstalling the Visual Studio (for Mac). Besides, you could also [Report a problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) with Visual Studio (for Mac).